# Solving complex polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

I am struggling to solve  $z^4+a^4=0$

I believe I need to use De Moivre's theorem, but not sure how to get it to work!

Answer (score 1):

If $a\ne0,$  we have  $\left(\dfrac za\right)^4=-1=e^{(2n+1)i\pi}$ where $n$ is any integer

$\implies\dfrac za=e^{\dfrac{(2n+1)i\pi}4}$ where $n\equiv0,1,2,3\pmod4$